# Import Firefox passwords into KeePassX or KeePass2

Tags: firefox, passwords, import

I have an XML export of my Firefox Passwords in the form (I replaced real passwords with ***):

```
<xml>
<entries ext="Password Exporter" extxmlversion="1.1" type="saved" encrypt="false">
<entry host="chrome://weave" user="****" password="****" formSubmitURL="" httpRealm="Mozilla Services Password" userFieldName="" passFieldName=""/>
<entry host="chrome://weave" user="****" password="****" formSubmitURL="" httpRealm="Mozilla Services Encryption Passphrase" userFieldName="" passFieldName=""/>
<entry host="http://www.example.de" user="rubo77" password="****" formSubmitURL="http://www.example.de" httpRealm="" userFieldName="benutzername" passFieldName="passwort"/>
<entry host="http://example2.de" user="qqq" password="pppp" formSubmitURL="http://example2.de" httpRealm="" userFieldName="username" passFieldName="pass"/>
...
```

Can I somehow convert this into a form KeePassX understands?

Comment: KeePassX has a very limited import-functionality. I'd guess the best way would be importing it into keepass2 and from there into keepassx.

Comment: that would be nice, How can I import this into KeePass2?